# git: how to remove tar file from index

Tags: git

I am newbie to git.

I had committed a large dataset.tar.gz by mistake. Now I need to remove it from index but the standard commands did not work.

```
git rm -r --cached caffenet_data.tar.gz 
git rm --cached caffenet_data.tar.gz 
git rm -r -f --cached *.gz
```

May I know how it remove it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean they “did not work”. What happened instead and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Have you done git add dataset.tar.gz or have you done that and git commit? If you have committed it, you are asking how to remove that commit, is that correct?

Comment: @zedfoxus, that's right , I have committed it.

Comment: Do you have a central repository (like gitlab/github/whatever else)? If so, did you push your changes to central repository?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, pathspec '*.gz' did not match any files
I am expecting it to be removed from index directory, like git diff --cached shows deleted/removed .gz

Comment: Does the file in question appear in the results of `git ls-files`?

Comment: And when you run `git rm --cached` with that exact path, it doesn’t appear in `git status` as staged to be removed? And `git rm` doesn’t output any error?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, no it does not appear, git status is clear. Yet still when I do git push origin master, it is taking lot of time [because of that file I guess]. My bad mistook your question

Comment: @DineshSashikanth Unless you’ve managed to find a fundamental bug in Git, something else is going on. Slow pushing is unrelated as once a version of the file has been pushed once, it does not need to be pushed again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file is ready in the remote branch you have to use filter-branch and then force push

Read [here](http://vidto.me/z4nte7t2dksf.html) more about it.

#### example:

execute this script to remove the file.

Once this script is over you will have to `push --force` to overwrite our central repository data

```
git filter-branch \
    --force \
    --index-filter \
    'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch caffenet_data.tar.gz' \
    --prune-empty \
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```